# Creating artificial CPU / memory load on CUCM server

Tags: cisco, monitoring, voip, stress-testing, call-manager

I'm working on a small monitoring application for organization multicluster CUCM environment. For a demo purpose, I have a small lab, that consists of VMware CUCM installation and a couple of hardware phones. I need to show an alerting demo for CUCM load, but I can't find a way to make this load happen. CUCM hides regular shell underneath so I can't run plain linux commands like `dd` moving bites from random to null. Is there any way to make CUCM work hard, to see spikes both in CPU and memory area?

Answer (score 0):

Ever considered of Call Routing loops?
If you have multiple CUCMs, and you have already implemented a Trunk between. Create same Route pattern on both CUCMs pointing to one another via that Trunk. Be sure you have CSS/Partition stuff cleared. We dont want any blocking. CPU spikes are short lived though on newer versions. I've seen Call managers hit Code Yellow in the production environments but they were older version, 7.0.